# How do I get an ILogger from NLog 3.1?

Tags: nlog, ilogger

I have a dotnet core library with a class that takes a Microsoft.Excentions.Logging.ILogger.  I need to call it from an existing .Net 4.7 application that uses NLog 3.1.

Is it possible to get an Ilooger from NLog3.1?

Comment: There are almost no breaking changes between NLog 3 and 4. (but there are many features and many many performance 
improvements in NLog 4)

Answer (score 1):

To capture logging from a dotnet core library that uses Microsoft Extension Logging ILogger, then you need to use this nuget-package to register NLog as logging provider:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/

See example here how to register NLog as logging provider:

- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application

But it will require you to upgrade NLog to version matching NLog.Extensions.Logging.